How to reuse the join alias made before on other relationship into an other relationship in sqlalchemy 2
I have a model with this attributes:
class VInterlocutori(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'v_interlocutori'

    origine: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(10), nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    origine_id: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(Integer, nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    descrizione: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(50), nullable=False)
    descrizione_breve: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(25), nullable=False)
    .
    .
    .


class Causali(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'causali'

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    descrizione: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(50), nullable=False)
    valoremax: Mapped[Decimal] = mapped_column(Numeric(8, 3), nullable=False, default=0)
    costomax: Mapped[Decimal] = mapped_column(Numeric(8, 3), nullable=False, default=0)
    numeratore: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, nullable=False, default=1)
    origineinterlocutore: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(10), nullable=False)
    .
    .
    .

class ListeTestata(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'liste_testata'

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    idcausale: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, ForeignKey(Causali.id), nullable=False)
    idinterlocutore: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, ForeignKey(VInterlocutori.origine_id), nullable=False)
    origine: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(3), ForeignKey(VNegoziMagazzini.cod_negozio), nullable=False)
    datacreazione: Mapped[datetime] = mapped_column(DateTime, nullable=False, default=func.now())
    
    causale: Mapped[Causali] = relationship(Causali, lazy="joined")
    interlocutore: Mapped[VInterlocutori] = relationship(VInterlocutori, lazy="joined",
                                                         primaryjoin=and_(idinterlocutore ==
                                                                         foreign(VInterlocutori.origine_id),
                                                                          foreign(Causali.origineinterlocutore) ==
                                                                          VInterlocutori.origine)
                                                         )


on my fastapi route I make the query:
@app.route(/)
def get_liste(db: Session):
    try:
        qry_liste = select(ListeTestata).where(ListeTesta.id == 2)
        rcds_liste = db.execute(qry_liste)
    except SQLAlchemyError as e:
        log.logger(e)
        raise HTTPException(500, "Internal error")
    else:
        return rods_liste 

but when sqlalchemy create the query the result is:
SELECT listearticoli.liste_testata.id,
       listearticoli.liste_testata.idcausale,
       listearticoli.liste_testata.idinterlocutore,
       listearticoli.liste_testata.origine,
       listearticoli.liste_testata.datacreazione,
       listearticoli.liste_testata.stato,
       listearticoli.liste_testata.idcalendario,
       listearticoli.liste_testata.identificativo,
       listearticoli.liste_testata.idzona,
       listearticoli.liste_testata.idcategoria,
       listearticoli.liste_testata.idrepartodes,
       v_interlocutori_1.origine          AS origine_2,
       v_interlocutori_1.origine_id,
       v_interlocutori_1.descrizione      AS descrizione_2,
       v_interlocutori_1.descrizione_breve,
       v_interlocutori_1.indirizzo,
       v_interlocutori_1.cap,
       v_interlocutori_1.comune,
       v_interlocutori_1.provincia,
       v_interlocutori_1.codice_fiscale,
       v_interlocutori_1.partita_iva,
       v_interlocutori_1.active,
       v_interlocutori_1.info_agg_01,
       v_interlocutori_1.info_agg_02,
       v_interlocutori_1.reso_diretto,
FROM listearticoli.liste_testata
         LEFT OUTER JOIN ods.v_negozi_magazzini AS v_negozi_magazzini_1
                         ON v_negozi_magazzini_1.cod_negozio = listearticoli.liste_testata.origine
         LEFT OUTER JOIN listearticoli.causali AS causali_1 ON causali_1.id = listearticoli.liste_testata.idcausale
         LEFT OUTER JOIN ods.v_interlocutori AS v_interlocutori_1
                         ON v_interlocutori_1.origine_id = listearticoli.liste_testata.idinterlocutore AND listearticoli.causali.origineinterlocutore = v_interlocutori_1.origine
where listearticoli.liste_testata = 2

how you can see on the join v_interlocutore sqlalchemy does't use the alias causali_1 but direct to the listearticoli.liste_testata.
the right query when sqlalchemy make the left outer join of the relationship VIinterlocutori should be:
SELECT listearticoli.liste_testata.id,
       listearticoli.liste_testata.idcausale,
       listearticoli.liste_testata.idinterlocutore,
       listearticoli.liste_testata.origine,
       listearticoli.liste_testata.datacreazione,
       listearticoli.liste_testata.stato,
       listearticoli.liste_testata.idcalendario,
       listearticoli.liste_testata.identificativo,
       listearticoli.liste_testata.idzona,
       listearticoli.liste_testata.idcategoria,
       listearticoli.liste_testata.idrepartodes,
       v_interlocutori_1.origine          AS origine_2,
       v_interlocutori_1.origine_id,
       v_interlocutori_1.descrizione      AS descrizione_2,
       v_interlocutori_1.descrizione_breve,
       v_interlocutori_1.indirizzo,
       v_interlocutori_1.cap,
       v_interlocutori_1.comune,
       v_interlocutori_1.provincia,
       v_interlocutori_1.codice_fiscale,
       v_interlocutori_1.partita_iva,
       v_interlocutori_1.active,
       v_interlocutori_1.info_agg_01,
       v_interlocutori_1.info_agg_02,
       v_interlocutori_1.reso_diretto,
FROM listearticoli.liste_testata
         LEFT OUTER JOIN ods.v_negozi_magazzini AS v_negozi_magazzini_1
                         ON v_negozi_magazzini_1.cod_negozio = listearticoli.liste_testata.origine
         LEFT OUTER JOIN listearticoli.causali AS causali_1 ON causali_1.id = listearticoli.liste_testata.idcausale
         LEFT OUTER JOIN ods.v_interlocutori AS v_interlocutori_1
                         ON v_interlocutori_1.origine_id = listearticoli.liste_testata.idinterlocutore AND
                            causali_1.origineinterlocutore = v_interlocutori_1.origine
where listearticoli.liste_testata = 2

Is there a way to force sqlalchemy to use the alias already created causali_1 to the relationship of interlocutore into ListeTestata model?
I tried to create an aliased with causali but It did't work. Can someone help me?

is it possible for you to show VInterlocutori and also make it a bit more copy pastable?

I updated the question to include VInterlocutori

thanks, I am sorry but your question is still not clear to me, can you add an example of the query (python code) you are trying to run?

I added the query that I'm doing, the relationship interlocutore in ListeTesta is lazy="joined" so each time I select ListeTesta should have the relationship with VInterlocutori but if sqlalchemy doesn't use the join already done with causali the select doen't work Postgres error: [42P01] ERROR: invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "causali" Suggerimento: Perhaps you meant to reference the table alias "causali_1".
